# MySql Subquery in PHP Not producing proper result

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I am working on this subquery in MySql:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
 patient_account
WHERE
   Doctor_ID IS NULL
 AND
   CONCAT(P_Fname, P_Lname, P_Mname) LIKE '%".$Search_Query."%'"
```

It should produce all patients who doesn't have a Doctor. But it produces patient records that has a doctor. is the syntax and logic of the query is right ?

Comment: seems legit. can you post `DESCRIBE patient_account`

Comment: We need a `SHOW CREATE TABLE patient_account`  and some example data

Comment: Where is the subquery pary in your query.. i dont see it

Answer (score 0):

[DESCRIBE patient_account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eva9C.png)

[Example of data produced (Supposed to be not produced)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbwB2.png)